# Is there an DispatchAfter equivalent in Xamarin Android?

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

```
var when = new DispatchTime(DispatchTime.Now, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.5));
DispatchQueue.MainQueue.DispatchAfter(when, () =>
{
    /* code here */
    Console.WriteLine("Dispatched!");
});
```

This utilizes the `DispatchQueue` as seen [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/corefoundation.dispatchqueue.dispatchafter?view=xamarin-ios-sdk-12#CoreFoundation_DispatchQueue_DispatchAfter_CoreFoundation_DispatchTime_System_Action_).

What would be the Android specific implementation or Xamarin.Forms platform independent solution to mimic this behavior across both platforms?

Note*: Not necessarily looking for `await Task.Delay(x-seconds)` solutions unless this is best practice. The dispatch queue doesn't appear to block any threads and works perfectly as is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want [Handler.PostDelayed()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/android.os.handler.postdelayed)